# commands for FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

what command use to convert avi MPEG to MP4 320x240 res, 24 fps?

Do you have any good manual for this (WINFFmpeg is out of way)?

Comment: MP4 is a _container_. There are many different codecs it can use; audio (MP3, AAC, Vorbis...) and video (MPEG4, Theora, H.264, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpeg -r 24 -s 320x240 output.mp4
```

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html .. just lookup the terms you used in your question.

Comment: What should I install as codec for MP4 for ffmpeg? Because it doesn't support mp4 as I see.

Comment: ffmpeg brings its codecs along. win32 builds:   http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/builds/

Comment: `ffmpeg -formats` lists what ffmpeg has builtin/available.

Comment: the default codec for mp4 container should be h.264

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a command-line program, someone not familiar with video conversion might try VLC instead.  The GUI might make your life a bit easier.

Comment: `HandBrake` is the free GUI alternative to `ffmpeg`.